# EditText inside ListView loses focus on keyboard show

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, commonsware-cwac

EditText inside ListView loses and gains focus 3 or 4 times when keyboard shows up. I have properly configured ListView (beforeDescendants) and Activity (adjustPan). I have over 500 items in ListView so I can't use ScrollView. I've made some research and I found that people had same problem. What keeps stealing focus during keyboard show up? Are views invalidated in that process?

Comment: `MergeAdapter` should not have an impact here. If you create a regular adapter that happens to return rows with `EditText` widgets in it, you should see similar behavior.

Comment: You are right. I have edited my question